# inline style not applied on dynamically created input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider:

```
  $( "#scanInDialogItems tr td:nth-child( 3 )").mouseenter( function() {
     var q = $( this ).html();
     $( this ).html( "<input type='number' style='text-align:right width:50px' min='1' value='" + q + "'/>" );
  }).mouseleave( function() { 
     var q = $( this ).find( "input" ).val();
     $( this ).html( q );
  });
```

Whenever the user hovers over a cell in the third column of my table, the content is replaced with an input element. Works like a charm.

The problem is that the inline styling for this element is not properly applied. E.g. the text in the box for example aligns left - the default. Also the width is not set.

I read in an earlier question that dynamically created input elements need to be refreshed when created:

[Styles not getting applied properly in dynamically created radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684089/styles-not-getting-applied-properly-in-dynamically-created-radio-buttons)

So I tried adding this:

```
     $( this ).find( "input" ).textinput( 'refresh' );
```

And or this:

```
     $( this ).find( "input" ).textinput();
```

But neither of those works. My target platform is the latest chrome.

Am I not refreshing input correctly? Or is there some other problem?

Comment: I think that link only applies to jQuery mobile. Anyways, can you give the `input` a class and then define the styling with CSS for that class? Does the `min` attribute work if you try to type in it? Like if you try to type in `-23`, does it show an error on the page?

Comment: Comment rather than answer, but it may help... Is it necessary to add your styles inline with your new markup, could they be anticipated in prior CSS instead?

Comment: I agree that it is better to put styles in css instead of inline. But inline is easier during development. I do a pass at the end creating styles in .css once I everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed a semicolon between text-align and width in the inline style...

```
$( "#scanInDialogItems tr td:nth-child( 3 )").mouseenter( function() {
    var q = $( this ).html();
    $( this ).html( "<input type='number' style='text-align:right;width:50px' min='1' value='" + q + "'/>" );
}).mouseleave( function() { 
    var q = $( this ).find( "input" ).val();
    $( this ).html( q );
});
```

I just tried a before & after in jsfiddle and that's all that was wrong with it :)